# How can I SELECT record from database WHERE a number is CLOSEST to one I supply?

Tags: sql-server, linq, t-sql

I am no database expert and really have no idea even how to approach this. I'm sure it is simple for someone who knows TSQL and would welcome some insights please.

I have a database with postcodes and Eastings and Northings. Example:

```
Postcode  Easting  Northing
---------------------------
HR74DW    365601   254668
B129DB    407863   284797
```

I would like to supply easting and northing values and return the closest single record (i.e. the postcode that matches). So, something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 Postcode 
FROM [PostcodeAddresses].[dbo].[FullPostcodeEastingNorthing] 
WHERE Easting (IS CLOSEST TO) 417940 
  AND Northing (IS CLOSEST TO) 284824.
```

I'm using .NET MVC 4 so it would also be very handy if someone knew how to do this using LINQ (but I'd still be delighted with TSQL.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: you could try to find the minimum pythagorean distance between your reference and the points in the DB, by replacing your `WHERE` clause with: `ORDER BY (easting-417940)*(easting-417940) + (northing-284824)*(northing-284824) ASC`

Comment: Though that would require a full scan every time. Have you looked at the geography datatype?

Comment: Note that the closest to `Easting` is not necessarily the closest to `Northing`. Maybe you want the one that minimizes both distances?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
       postcode, 
       ABS(Easting  - 417940) AS MinEasting,
       ABS(Northing - 284824) AS MinNorthing
    FROM FullPostcodeEastingNorthing
)
SELECT postcode
FROM FullPostcodeEastingNorthing
WHERE ABS(Easting - 417940 ) = (SELECT MIN(MinEasting)
                                FROM CTE)
  AND ABS(Northing - 284824) = (SELECT MIN(MinNorthing)
                                FROM CTE);
```

See it in action here:

- [**SQL Fidle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f97aa/1)

Comment: This looks amazing! I see it works perfectly in the Fiddle! It is most likely something I'm doing but when I run the query in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 against the actual database I get no records returned? I have 678,948 records in the database and they are formatted as above. I'm wondering if I'm missing something?

Comment: @user975516 I think the problem is in the `AND`, it is not necessary that the postalcode has the both the `MIN` of both the difference between the `Easting` and `Northing`.

Comment: OK, just ran the example above and created a new table with just the two entries and this works. However, when I have the 678,948 records it doesn't return a value - any ideas? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I am using @w0lf's suggestion as it works well and the database is not so large and the number of queries are low - so a small delay for a full scan is acceptable.

Here's the postcode I am using as an example:

```
SELECT [Postcode], [Easting], [Northing]
  FROM [PostcodeAddresses].[dbo].[FullPostcodeEastingNorthing]
  WHERE Postcode = 'GU147NL'
```

```
Postcode  Easting  Northing
---------------------------
GU147NL   486871   156016
```

Here is how I return the postcode using @w0lf's suggestion. You can see how the eastings and northings are NOT the same as above, but ARE close and it DOES return the right postcode.

```
SELECT TOP 1 Postcode 
FROM [PostcodeAddresses].[dbo].[FullPostcodeEastingNorthing] 
ORDER BY (easting-486860)*(easting-486860) 
+ (northing-156007)*(northing-156007) 
ASC
```

```
Postcode
--------
GU147NL
```

Thanks @w0lf!